# Azure Web App - Route Different External Domains to Different Directories in "site"

Tags: azure, web, dns

I've searched high and low for the answer to my question and after weeding through possible solutions that might or might not have anything to do with my question, I broke down and here I am. I apologize before hand if this is a repeat.

Quick Background:

My background with Azure is limited, but I am learning.

We are in Germany. My customer has decided that we move all our websites to his Azure Platform from our current virtual server by STRATO. We have 5 websites that currently exist on the virtual server that need to be moved. All are PHP/MySQL, we have everything set up in our Azure for this, so no problem there.

Since the domain TLDs are .de and .plus and you cannot add these to Azure itself (something that continuously baffles me to this day), we have to do the DNS record edit by STRATO, that part I understand as well.

The directory structure is the folder "site" and then five separate subfolders, 1 per website. This is normal.

The Azure has one subdomain - xxx.azurewebsites.net, this points to the empty folder "wwwroot", which isn't a problem either.

Here are the two things that are driving me nuts:

1. How exactly do I point each incoming Domain to its specific subdirectory in the tree? Remembering that the websites are PHP and not ASP.NET, there is, of course, no web.config file.
2. Where is the "safe-zone" within the directory structure? By this, I mean the part of the subdirectory in the Azure tree that is not accessible by any domain. We have a directory that houses semi-sensitive information in the current structure that can only be accessed by the classes in each app, but is not accessible from the internet. I moved copies of the websites to subdirectories within "site", my thinking is the safe directory would normally be another directory under "site", but is my assumption correct? This question seems ultra-simple, but I have to be absolutely sure because of the contents in the folder.

I read in another post that we would require one Web App per incoming domain, I hope this isn't the case.

I will gladly provide any additional information if it would help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I read in another post that we would require one Web App per incoming domain, I hope this isn't the case." - why would that be a problem? Might be a much better solution in terms of separation of concerns. You can run them all on 1 App Service Plan, thus the costs are the same. Then, based on your need, you could put something like Azure FrontDoor in front of them and do path-based routing

Comment: Thanks for the info, like I said, I am rather new to Azure, wasn't sure if there were additional costs attached. I will get with the team and see what is possible. Still, any other info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would recommend to go with this setup:

- An Azure FrontDoor (AFD) as your entry point. [Add your custom domain(s)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-custom-domain) to AFD.
- Multiple App Services, one for each of your apps. Then you do not need to worry about subfolders etc. Deploy each app to its own service (in the root directory)
- You can run all App Services on one App Service Plan (which is what you pay for).
- Add each App Service as a Backend in AFD
- [Add routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/quickstart-create-front-door) based on the path in AFD
- Optionally enable Web Application Firewall in AFD
- Lock down traffic on the App Services to only come from AFD by adding an [Access restriction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) based on Service Tags for Azure Front Door
  [image]

Comment: Perfectly what I am looking for. I will propose this to my customer today. As soon as we test this and it works I will mark this as the answer. Appreciate your help!

Comment: glad it helped!